# Column containing keys from columns of another table

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key, table

I have two csv files, countries and birth_rate_stat with the following data:

| ISO | ISO3 | ISO_CODE | FIPS | Display Name | Currency Name | Phone_Code | Region Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AF | AFG | 4 | AF | Afghanistan | Afghani | 93 | Asia |
| AX | ALA | 248 |  | Aland Islands | Euro | 340 | Europe |

| country_code | country_name | year | birth_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SI | Slovenia | 2036 | 7.59 |
| SI | Slovenia | 2022 | 7.52 |

and  i created two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
      `iso` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `iso3` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
      `iso_code` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `fips` varchar(2) DEFAULT UNIQUE,
      `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `currency_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `phone_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `region_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`iso`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `birth_rate_stat` (
     `iso` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
     `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `crude_birth_rate` float NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`iso`,`year`),
     CONSTRAINT `crude_birth_rate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`iso`) REFERENCES `countries` (`iso`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The problem that i face while trying to connect the birth_rate_stat table with the countries one is that, in the birth_rate_stat table, the column country_code contains entries from both the `ISO` and the `FIPS` columns from the table countries. That means I can't set `iso` as a primary key nor `fips` as `fips` contains null values. I tried to create a `country_id` column which would distinguish the countries but then i get an error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` which makes sense since it doesn't exist in birth_rate_stat.

Do you have some suggestions as to how i could connect the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A** -- Cleanse the code as you insert it.

That is, decide that *all* entries will have, say, `iso` and that `fips` is optional.  There are plenty of online tables that map those two sets of codes; download one of them for your use.

**Plan B** -- If that is not possible, then change to something like

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `iso` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `iso3` CHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iso_code` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `fips` CHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_code` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_code` SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE(`iso`),
   UNIQUE(`fips`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Notes:

- You will have to join on `id`, not `iso`.
- `UNIQUE` allows multiple rows to have `NULL`, but `PRIMARY KEY` does not.
- I changed several datatypes.
- Consider changing to `utf8mb4` to allow each country to have its own spelling.  (Or maybe have another column for such.)